# Applying the style to new created items in shopping list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to have an event that will cross out each of clicked items INCLUDING those which the user created by himself.

I have a "To Do" list which contains 4 items by default. You can add your "to dos" by entering them in input field.
P.S - now my script works only for existing items

```js
var input = document.getElementById("inpText");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createNewListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
}

function newElementCreation() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createNewListElement();
    }
}

function newElementCreationByEnter(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createNewListElement();
    }
}

function ElementToggling () {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
}

    button.addEventListener("click", newElementCreation);
    input.addEventListener("keypress", newElementCreationByEnter);

for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
   list[i].addEventListener("click", ElementToggling);
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        To do list
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My to do list for today</h1>
    <input id="inpText" type="text" placeholder="enter the value">
    <button id="button">Add</button>
    <ul>
        <li>To brush my teeth</li>
        <li>To cover the bed</li>
        <li>To dress up</li>
        <li>To cook my breakfast</li>
    </ul>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach the *click* event on the newly created *li*.

Update: Added one counter variable to keep the track of total *li* count.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("inpText");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var totalEl = list.length;
console.log('Total element:', totalEl);

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createNewListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
    li.addEventListener("click", ElementToggling); // attach the event here
    totalEl++; // Increment the count
    console.log('Total element:', totalEl);
}

function newElementCreation() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createNewListElement();
    }
}

function newElementCreationByEnter(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createNewListElement();
    }
}

function ElementToggling () {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
}

    button.addEventListener("click", newElementCreation);
    input.addEventListener("keypress", newElementCreationByEnter);

for (let i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
   list[i].addEventListener("click", ElementToggling);
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<h1>My to do list for today</h1>
<input id="inpText" type="text" placeholder="enter the value">
<button id="button">Add</button>
<ul>
    <li>To brush my teeth</li>
    <li>To cover the bed</li>
    <li>To dress up</li>
    <li>To cook my breakfast</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to sort out how to work with "let" properly. And how to count the list length in this case?
If I count it inside the "for" loop - it calculates only the existing items. 
If I set a counter  inside the  Function - it calculates new items only

Comment: @NikitaBasharkin, There is nothing to do with *let* here. You can maintain a global variable and increment that when a new *li* is created, updated the answer....thanks:)

Comment: Thank you! Mach appreciate your response!:)

Comment: @NikitaBasharkin, you are most welcome, glad to help:)